# Loading TreeStore with JSON that has different children fields

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4.1

I am having a JSON data like below.

```
{
    "divisions": [{
        "name": "division1",
        "id": "div1",
        "subdivisions": [{
            "name": "Sub1Div1",
            "id": "div1sub1",
            "schemes": [{
                "name": "Scheme1",
                "id": "scheme1"
            }, {
                "name": "Scheme2",
                "id": "scheme2"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Sub2Div1",
            "id": "div1sub2",
            "schemes": [{
                "name": "Scheme3",
                "id": "scheme3"
            }]
        }

        ]
    }]
}
```

I want to read this into a TreeStore, but cannot change the subfields ( `divisions`, `subdivisions`, `schemes` ) to be the same (eg, `children`).

How can achieve I this?

Answer (score 7):

When nested JSON is loaded into a TreeStore, essentially the children nodes are loaded through a recursive calls between `TreeStore.fillNode()` method and `NodeInterface.appendChild()`.

The actual retrieval of each node's children field is done within `TreeStore.onNodeAdded()` on this line:

```
dataRoot = reader.getRoot(data);
```

The `getRoot()` of the reader is dynamically created in the reader's `buildExtractors()` method, which is what you'll need to override in order to deal with varying children fields within nested JSON. Here is how it's done:

```
Ext.define('MyVariJsonReader', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    alias : 'reader.varijson',

    buildExtractors : function()
    {
        var me = this;    
        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.getRoot = function ( aObj ) {                
            // Special cases
            switch( aObj.name )
            {
                case 'Bill':   return aObj[ 'children' ];
                case 'Norman': return aObj[ 'sons' ];                    
            }

            // Default root is `people`
            return aObj[ 'people' ];
        };
    }
});
```

This will be able to interpret such JSON:

```
{
   "people":[
      {
         "name":"Bill",
         "expanded":true,
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Kate",
               "leaf":true
            },
            {
               "name":"John",
               "leaf":true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Norman",
         "expanded":true,
         "sons":[
            {
               "name":"Mike",
               "leaf":true
            },
            {
               "name":"Harry",
               "leaf":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

See [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/fF5Ux/) for fully working code.