# ExtJS 4.0.7 Load complete TreePanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am in trouble with the ExtJS 4.0.7 TreePanel. I would like to load the complete tree from on JSON request. The request returns the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "OS",
        "leaf": false,
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "Hostname",
            "leaf": false,
            "children": [
              {
                "text": "hostname.int.com",
                "leaf": true,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With it doesn't work with the following store configuration (or any other i've tried)

```
Ext.define('My.store.SysInfo', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'My.model.SysInfo',

    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : '/sysinfo/getSysInfo.php',
        reader : {
            root : 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

The Model has the following code:

```
Ext.define('My.model.SysInfo', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['text']
});
```

When adding a treepanel with this configuration, it doesn't work:

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    name : 'sysinfo',
    height: '100%',
    store: 'My.store.SysInfo',
    lines: true,
    autoScroll : true,
    expanded : true,
    rootVisible: false,
    folderSort: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    useArrows: true,
}
```

By opening a node, ExtJS always loads the whole tree from it's root node into the subnode by requesting it via ajax, instead of showing the preloaded data. How can i achieve, that it loads the "Hostname" node by opening "OS"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely do that. But there seems to be an issue with your json.

The root of your json is `data`, but in order for the nested data to load correctly, your root and all children properties need to be the same. Since you have defined your reader's root as `data`, you should replace all `children` in your json to `data`.

Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040130/), and if you fancy a deeper understanding of it all also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092123/loading-treestore-with-json-that-has-different-children-fields/12092938#12092938). You can also have a look at this [working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/3hmfQ/).

If you define your reader like so:

```
    reader : {
        type: 'json',
        // root : 'children' // no real need for this a children is the default.
    }
```

This json should load correctly:

```
{
  "children":[
     {
        "text":"OS",
        "leaf":false,
        "children":[
           {
              "text":"Hostname",
              "leaf":false,
              "children":[
                 {
                    "text":"hostname.int.com",
                    "leaf":true,
                    "children":[

                    ]
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```