# Extjs setRootNode() on TreeGrid isn't loading children of the object

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am currently building a project using Ext JS 4.2 this is the first time I am using TreeGrids and TreeStores so it is very possible I am misunderstanding the structure somewhere. Currently the issue seems to be when I use setRootNode(JSON) it refreshes the tree but it only displays the root node and none of its children. Here is what it currently creates.

Using the developer tools in chrome this is what the object looks like before it is passed in.

```
Object {text: ".", Item Number: "P00001", original: "P00001", children: Array[2]}
```

Once it is passed in using setRootNode(Object) it only displays the root. However I have noticed that looking at the grid.tree.root property all the data is in there which makes me wonder why it is not being loaded into the treegrid.

Here is a snippet of my code that loads the necessary data. var grid refers to the tree panel component. store.load causes a jsp call that loads in meta data that dynamically creates the columns / fields for the treegrid and model which is functioning correctly.

```
onPanelAfterRender: function(){
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('BOMGrid');
    var store = Ext.getStore('BOMGridStore');
    store.load();
    //var me = Ext.getCmp('main-page');
    grid.setLoading('Loading BOM...');
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'loadbom.jsp',    
        timeout: 300000,
        params : {
        },
        success: function (response, opt) {
            grid.setLoading(false);
            var res = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            if (res.success) {  
                console.debug(res.results[0]);
                grid.setRootNode(res.results[0]);
            }
            else {
                    console.debug("JSON failure");
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Invalid part number');
            }

        },
        failure: function(response,options){
            console.debug("major failure");
            grid.setLoading(false);
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Connection failed<br>' + response.responseText);
            }
        });
}
```

If you need additional information or for me to clarify something please ask me I would appreciate any help that I could possibly get.

Comment: As far as i know ExtJS loads tree "lazily" by default. So try clicking-expanding your root. Also check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176410/extjs-4-0-7-load-complete-treepanel

Comment: may be this will help you.. http://jsfiddle.net/ATechieDiary/5x8hH/

Comment: @Роман Гуйван I just fixed up my JSON code and now when I call the getRootNode() method it now shows that there is data in the root node however now nothing is showing in my TreeGrid. This is part of the getRootNode() call.
{raw: Object, modified: Object, data: Object, hasListeners: statics.prepareClass.l, events: Object…}
childNodes: Array[1]
  0: z
    childNodes: Array[2]