# EXTJS 5.1 VERY SIMPLE TreeStore from JSON

Tags: extjs, tree, store, extjs5

I have looked around but I still don't understand how to create treestore properly.
I have this very simple json that I get from a server:

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 23,
      "cars": [
        {
          "name": "Clio",
          "brand": "Renault"
        },
        {
          "name": "Class S",
          "brand": "Mercedes"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Michel",
      "age": 42,
      "cars": [
        {
          "name": "Qashqai",
          "brand": "Nissan"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have my two models:

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'name', 'age']
});

Ext.define('Car', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'name', 'brand']
});
```

Now I know that I have to create a tree store, but in all example that I have seen, there is always a "children" property in the json, which I don't have.

How to create a tree store with the following json?

Thanks a lot in advance :) !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always build the correct formatted object for the data like the following:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        var myTreeData = {
                "Results": [{
                    "name": "John",
                    "age": 23,
                    "cars": [{
                        "name": "Clio",
                        "brand": "Renault"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Class S",
                        "brand": "Mercedes"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "name": "Michel",
                    "age": 42,
                    "cars": [{
                        "name": "Qashqai",
                        "brand": "Nissan"
                    }]
                }]
            },
            modifiedData = {
                expanded: true,
                children: []
            };
        myTreeData.Results.forEach(function (result) {
            var newChildrenArray = [];
            result.cars.forEach(function (car) {
                var newChild = {
                    text: car.name,
                    leaf: true
                };
                newChildrenArray.push(newChild);
            });
            var person = {
                text: result.name,
                leaf: (newChildrenArray.length > 0 ? false : true),
                children: newChildrenArray
            };
            modifiedData.children.push(person);
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            root: modifiedData
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            title: 'Simple Tree',
            width: 200,
            height: 150,
            store: store,
            rootVisible: false,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Demo here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j05

Comment: Even if I didn't want to modify the json (because I have a 10mo json file received from the server), I think you're right, and there is any other way.

I thought that there woud be some configs to say "cars is the children property", or something like this ^^.

Thank you very much for your help Rob :) !

Comment: @JkSuf you can also look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12092938/1672632 which has another approach.